# Having issue with a trigger that fires after a row in a table is updated/inserted/deleted

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have a small system that I've had to create for an assignment. It's meant to make viewing relevant data in the database easier for "management".

I have three tables:

- `CLIENT` just contains a client id, client name, phone number, and email.
- `PROJECT` is just as simple. It has a project id, client id that references `CLIENT`, and a project name.
- `PROJECT_PAYMENT` contains a project payment id, project id that references `PROJECT`, and then a load of rows that have payment due date, amount paid, amount oustanding, etc etc.

I then have four views:

- `PAYMENTS_COMPLETED` which shows, you guessed it, completed payments.
- `PAYMENTS_OUTSTANDING` which is the opposite of the above.
- `PAYMENTS_DISPUTED` which shows any payments that have been disputed by either the client or the company.
- `PAYMENTS_PAST_DUE` which shows payments that have not been completed, and where the payment due date has passed.

I then have a procedure that updates all of these four views:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE UPDATE_VIEWS AUTHID CURRENT_USER
IS

PAYMENTS_COMPLETED_STMNT VARCHAR2(5000);
PAYMENTS_DISPUTED_STMNT VARCHAR2(5000);
PAYMENTS_OUTSTANDING_STMNT VARCHAR2(5000);
PAYMENTS_PAST_DUE_STMNT VARCHAR2(5000);

BEGIN

    PAYMENTS_COMPLETED_STMNT := 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW PAYMENTS_COMPLETED AS SELECT PP.PROJECT_PAYMENT_ID, P.PROJECT_NAME, C.CLIENT_ID, C.CLIENT_NAME, PP.PAYMENT_DUE, PP.PAYMENT_TOTAL FROM PROJECT_PAYMENT PP JOIN PROJECT P ON PP.PROJECT_ID = P.PROJECT_ID JOIN CLIENT C ON C.CLIENT_ID = P.CLIENT_ID WHERE PP.PAYMENT_PAID >= PP.PAYMENT_TOTAL';
    PAYMENTS_DISPUTED_STMNT := 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW PAYMENTS_DISPUTED AS SELECT PP.PROJECT_PAYMENT_ID, P.PROJECT_NAME, C.CLIENT_ID, C.CLIENT_NAME, PP.PAYMENT_DUE, PP.PAYMENT_TOTAL, PP.PAYMENT_PAID, PP.PAYMENT_TOTAL-PP.PAYMENT_PAID AS "PAYMENT_REMAINING", PP.PAYMENT_DISPUTED_CLIENT, PP.PAYMENT_DISPUTED_COMPANY FROM PROJECT_PAYMENT PP JOIN PROJECT P ON PP.PROJECT_ID = P.PROJECT_ID JOIN CLIENT C ON C.CLIENT_ID = P.CLIENT_ID WHERE UPPER(PP.PAYMENT_DISPUTED_CLIENT) = ''Y'' OR UPPER(PP.PAYMENT_DISPUTED_COMPANY) = ''Y''';
    PAYMENTS_OUTSTANDING_STMNT := 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW PAYMENTS_OUTSTANDING AS SELECT PP.PROJECT_PAYMENT_ID, P.PROJECT_NAME, C.CLIENT_ID, C.CLIENT_NAME, PP.PAYMENT_DUE, PP.PAYMENT_TOTAL, PP.PAYMENT_PAID, PP.PAYMENT_TOTAL - PP.PAYMENT_PAID AS "PAYMENT_REMAINING" FROM PROJECT_PAYMENT PP JOIN PROJECT P ON PP.PROJECT_ID = P.PROJECT_ID JOIN CLIENT C ON C.CLIENT_ID = P.CLIENT_ID WHERE PP.PAYMENT_PAID < PP.PAYMENT_TOTAL';
    PAYMENTS_PAST_DUE_STMNT := 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW PAYMENTS_PAST_DUE AS SELECT PP.PROJECT_PAYMENT_ID, P.PROJECT_NAME, C.CLIENT_ID, C.CLIENT_NAME, PP.PAYMENT_DUE, PP.PAYMENT_TOTAL, PP.PAYMENT_PAID, PP.PAYMENT_TOTAL-PP.PAYMENT_PAID AS "PAYMENT_REMAINING" FROM PROJECT_PAYMENT PP JOIN PROJECT P ON PP.PROJECT_ID = P.PROJECT_ID JOIN CLIENT C ON C.CLIENT_ID = P.CLIENT_ID WHERE PP.PAYMENT_DUE < TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND PP.PAYMENT_PAID < PP.PAYMENT_TOTAL';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE PAYMENTS_COMPLETED_STMNT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('UPDATED PAYMENTS_COMPLETED VIEW.');
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE PAYMENTS_DISPUTED_STMNT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('UPDATED PAYMENTS_DISPUTED VIEW.');
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE PAYMENTS_OUTSTANDING_STMNT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('UPDATED PAYMENTS_OUTSTANDING VIEW.');
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE PAYMENTS_PAST_DUE_STMNT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('UPDATED PAYMENTS_PAST_DUE VIEW.');

END;
```

Now on to my issue. I created the following trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER UPDATE_VIEWS_ON_PP_INSERT_TG
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON PROJECT_PAYMENT
BEGIN
    UPDATE_VIEWS();
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ALL VIEWS HAVE BEEN UPDATED.');
END;
```

My intention was that it would fire whenever someone inserted a new row, updated a row, or deleted a row from `PROJECT_PAYMENT`. The trigger *does* fire, however it gives me the following error, and stops the row I just tried to insert from being committed:

```
One error saving changes to table "O015596H"."PROJECT_PAYMENT":
Row 11: ORA-04092: cannot COMMIT in a trigger
ORA-06512: at "O015596H.UPDATE_VIEWS", line 16
ORA-06512: at "O015596H.UPDATE_VIEWS_ON_PP_INSERT_TG", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'O015596H.UPDATE_VIEWS_ON_PP_INSERT_TG'
ORA-06512: at line 1

Local changes cleared
```

I have no idea what this error means or how to fix it, so was helping someone here could tell me what the issue is. I know it says it cannot commit in a trigger, but I don't know how I am meant to get rid of the error.

EDIT 1:

I Googled around and saw that adding:

```
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSATION;
```

... above the "BEGIN" line would work, but now I am getting an "insuffienct privileges" error:

```
One error saving changes to table "O015596H"."PROJECT_PAYMENT":
Row 11: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "O015596H.UPDATE_VIEWS", line 16
ORA-06512: at "O015596H.UPDATE_VIEWS_ON_PP_INSERT_TG", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'O015596H.UPDATE_VIEWS_ON_PP_INSERT_TG'
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: It says that procedure `update_views` commits data (line 16). You cannot commit in trigger.

Comment: I googled around and apparently there is a way around it. Please see my edit.

Comment: @JohnYuki a view is a stored query. You don’t need to update it when the underlying data changes.

Answer (score 2):

Views are **permanent** database structures. Just write DDL scripts as you would for tables or anything else. Run them once and give privileges on the views to the people who need access. Job's a good 'un.

Apart from anything else, you don't want to be re-creating those objects every time somebody records a project payment. Getting object locks would be a pain in the neck and users would find their attempts to query those views constantly failing because of session state invalidations.

To explain the errors you got:

> ORA-04092: cannot COMMIT in a trigger

DDL in Oracle - such as CREATE VIEW statements - issue implicit commits. Oracle does not allow us to include COMMIT (or ROLLBACK) in a trigger because triggers fire as part of the transaction but the transaction is not necessarily complete when the trigger fires.

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Looks like you have CREATE VIEW privilege granted through a role. We cannot use roles granted indirectly through roles in program units (stored procedures, views or triggers).

---

> the assignment specifies that I have to demonstrate knowledge on how to use procedures, functions, and triggers.

Using a trigger to create a view doesn't demonstrate that you know *"how to use procedures, functions, and triggers"*. Rather the opposite in fact.

A simpler and better use of a trigger would be to use `amount paid` to maintain `amount outstanding` on PROJECT_PAYMENT.

```
create or replace TRIGGER UPDATE_VIEWS_ON_PP_INSERT_TG
before update ON PROJECT_PAYMENT for each row
BEGIN
    :new.amount_outstanding := :old.amount_outstanding - :new.amount_paid;
END;
```

This reduces the `amount outstanding` by the amount of the newest payment. (I have assumed each record in PROJECT_PAYMENT represents a single payment, and `amount_paid` is not a rolling total.)

Comment: Sorry I should have specified that I am quite new to SQL so I don't understand a lot of the terminology. What is a DDL script, how do I give privileges to myself in order to get the trigger to work as I want it to?

Comment: @JohnYuki . . . If you are new to SQL, triggers are probably not the best place to start.  You don't need triggers or stored procedures to create these views.

Comment: It is for an assignment, and the assignment specifies that I have to demonstrate knowledge on how to use procedures, functions, and triggers. When I say "new", I don't mean brand new, but not experienced enough that I could really apply for an entry-level database developer position.

Comment: *"What is a DDL script"* - it's whatever you used to create those tables.

Comment: DDL = Data Definition Language, typically any command  beginning with `create`, `alter`, `drop`, or `truncate` (there are more). These are permanent changes to the schema.